# what is an alternative to method overloading to make code a bit less repetitive c#

Tags: c#, string, methods, int, double

I am stuck with method overloading and I would like to know how toy could possibly simplify or redo so that I can make it one function

I would like to know
how would I be able to simplify this ->

```
    print(5);
    print(5.5);
    print("5");  

    static void print (int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    static void print (string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    static void print (double x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Into something like this ->

```
    print(5);
    print(5.5);
    print("5");  

    static void print (int x, string y, double, z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed take an object type as parameter, as mentioned before. I myself prefer the more elegant solution using generics:

```
static void print<T>(T x) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Elegant and totally useless, because `Console.WriteLine` accepts an `object` as parameter, there is no utility in making that specific method generic. It will just make the compiler generate different methods (which will all do the same thing).

Comment: Console.WriteLine may accept an object type as parameter, but asker's print function does not.

Answer (score 1):

Make your param a generic `object`:

```
static void print (object o)
{
    ConSole.WriteLine(o);
}
```

this will implicitely call `o.ToString`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can avoid multiple overloads if you only use common members of the different types that you think you need to handle differently. In your example, you don't need overloads at all since all of the types you want to handle have a `ToString` method that they inherit from `object`. Thus you could just simply write:

```
void print(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

Assume you want to handle numbers and strings differently, you can also use the fact that `int` is implicitly casted to `double`. So there is no need for a separate `int` overload if it would do the same as on `double`:

```
void print(double d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am a number " + d.ToString());
}

print(1);
print(1.0); // both works
```

So the goal is always to find the common base class/interface or implicit type conversion to avoid redundant method overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You DID simply it, but your function call would look like this:

```
print(5, 5.5, "5");
```

Your function would look like this:

```
static void print (int x, string y, double z)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    Console.WriteLine(z);
}
```

Comment: he does not mean that i think. He shows the tree examples where you call the `print` function with different parameter types.

Comment: Oh, wow. I really missed that. I would use generics but object works too. Thanks.